# job client must be a coordinationrequestgateway. this is a bug

Tags: apache-flink, flink-table-api

We are using flink tableApi and while performing executeQuery operation, we run into this issue .
Basically everything works completely fine from local but when we run the same application using on flinkUI, we see below exception.

```
org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.RestHandlerException: Could not execute application.
at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(JarRunHandler.java:108)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:836)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:811)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1609)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: Could not execute application.
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:273)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:280)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1606)
... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: Could not execute application.
at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.DetachedApplicationRunner.tryExecuteJobs(DetachedApplicationRunner.java:88)
at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.DetachedApplicationRunner.run(DetachedApplicationRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandler.lambda$handleRequest$0(JarRunHandler.java:102)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: Failed to execute sql
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:372)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222)
at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:114)
at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.DetachedApplicationRunner.tryExecuteJobs(DetachedApplicationRunner.java:84)
... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Failed to execute sql
at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeQueryOperation(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:812)
at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:1225)
at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeSql(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:730)
at com.here.platform.extensions.pipelinetemplate.util.FlinkTableApi$.executeEnricherFunction(FlinkTableApi.scala:63)
at com.here.platform.extensions.pipelinetemplate.stream2iml.EventStream2ImlViaTableApi$.$anonfun$moveDataFromStream2Iml$1(EventStream2ImlViaTableApi.scala:95)
at com.here.platform.extensions.pipelinetemplate.stream2iml.EventStream2ImlViaTableApi$.$anonfun$moveDataFromStream2Iml$1$adapted(EventStream2ImlViaTableApi.scala:90)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:32)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:29)
at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:37)
at com.here.platform.extensions.pipelinetemplate.stream2iml.EventStream2ImlViaTableApi$.moveDataFromStream2Iml(EventStream2ImlViaTableApi.scala:90)
at com.here.platform.extensions.pipelinetemplate.usecase.EventStreamToImlConversion$.runWithEventToFeaturesConverter(EventStreamToImlConversion.scala:59)
at com.here.platform.extensions.pipelinetemplate.usecase.StreamingUseCases$.eventStreamToIml(StreamingUseCases.scala:42)
at com.here.platform.extensions.validationrepair.EventStream2Iml$.runPipeline(EventStream2Iml.scala:24)
at com.here.platform.extensions.validationrepair.EventStream2Iml$.delayedEndpoint$com$here$platform$extensions$validationrepair$EventStream2Iml$1(EventStream2Iml.scala:27)
at com.here.platform.extensions.validationrepair.EventStream2Iml$delayedInit$body.apply(EventStream2Iml.scala:16)
at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
at com.here.platform.extensions.validationrepair.EventStream2Iml$.main(EventStream2Iml.scala:16)
at com.here.platform.extensions.validationrepair.EventStream2Iml.main(EventStream2Iml.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355)
... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Job client must be a CoordinationRequestGateway. This is a bug.
at org.apache.flink.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:138)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultFetcher.setJobClient(CollectResultFetcher.java:89)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultIterator.setJobClient(CollectResultIterator.java:101)
at org.apache.flink.table.planner.connectors.CollectDynamicSink$1.setJobClient(CollectDynamicSink.java:63)
at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeQueryOperation(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:797)
... 41 common frames omitted
```

**Root cause identified :**

Seems like this happens when we use executeSql which internally uses execute() and collect()

**Issue resolved:**
We were able to resolve this issue by using temporary views on top of sqlQuery instead of using collect on tableResult

Answer (score 0):

Using temporary views instead of performing collect on tableResult solved the issue.